# Import XML file greater than 2 GB to DB2 9.7

Tags: xml, db2, db2-luw

I wrote a Java program that streams an XML file greater than 2GB in the database. It worked for version db2 version 10.5.5 on windows but failed with the following error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.26 on DB2 Linux 9.7. 
I get to understand that this means that the data being sent is greater than the column size. I am wondering if there is an issue with DB2 9.7 why the program works on 10.5 only and if so, please suggest a fix for the is problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is that prior to DB2 for LUW v10.1 XML data were serialized into character data for transfer between the JDBC client and the server, and there is a limit of 2 GB on the serialized XML. Beginning with version 10.1 XML data are transferred in binary form by default and the serialization limit does not apply.

If you must work with the outdated DB2 v9.7 I think you might be able to use the DB2 `LOAD` command to insert your XML files, as was suggested in response to your previous question.

References:

1. [SQL and XML limits](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F2-9-9&lang=en) (search for "serialized XML").
2. Binary XML format -- [new in DB2 10.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0057210.html?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've being searching for this information and its consuming a lot of my time. I'm going to have to write a report on this finding; could you provide me with a reference to verify this information in my report.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I tried the DB2 load command like you suggested. It works for smaller xml files but still failed for the xml file with size above 2 GB.  Here is the error that I got: SQL3306N An SQL error "-901" occurred while inserting a row into the table. SQL0901N The SQL statement or command failed because of  a database system error. (Reason """.) SQL SSTATE=58004 SQL3110N